# How to parse query param effectively in java?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, deserialization

All I have is the request URI from which I have to parse the query params. What I'm doing is adding them to json/hashmap and fetching again like the following

```
String requestUri = "name=raju&school=abcd&college=mnop&color=black&fruit=mango";
```

All I have to do is to finally assign it to variables like the following

```
String name = "raju";
String school = "abcd";
String college = "mnop";
String color = "black";
String fruit = "mango";
```

So I am parsing the request uri like the following

```
String[] paramsKV = requestUri.split("&");
JSONArray jsonKVArr = new JSONArray();
for (String params : paramsKV) {
    String[] tempArr = params.split("=");
    if(tempArr.length>1) {
        String key = tempArr[0];
        String value = tempArr[1];
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put(key, value);
        jsonKVArr.put(jsonObj);
     }
 }
```

The another way is to populate the same in hash map and obtain the same. The other way is to match the `requestUri` string with regex pattern and obtain the results.

Say for an example to get the value of `school` I have to match the values between the starting point of the string `school` and the next `&` - which doesn't sound good.

1. What is the better approach to parse the query String in java?
2. How could i handle the following thing in a better way?

I need to construct another hash map like the following from the above results like

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>;

resultMap.put("empname", name);
resultMap.put("rschool", school);
resultMap.put("empcollege", college);
resultMap.put("favcolor", color);
resultMap.put("favfruit", fruit);
```

To make it simple all I have to do is to parse the query param and construct a hashMap by naming the `key` filed differently. How could I do it in a simple way? Any help in this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another possible solution:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([^&=]+)=([^&]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(requestUri);
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: Every HTTP Client library will do this for you.

Example: Apache HttpClient's [URLEncodedUtils](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) class

```
String queryComponent = "name=raju&school=abcd&college=mnop&color=black&fruit=mango";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(queryComponent, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

They're basically approaching it the same way. Parameter key-value pairs are delimited by `&` and the keys from the values by `=` so String's `split` is appropriate for both.

From what I can tell however your hashmap inserts are mapping new keys to the existing values so there's really no optimization, save maybe for moving to a Java 8 Stream for readability/maintenance and/or discarding the initial jsonArray and mapping straight to the hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 and store your data in HashMap in one operation.

```
Map<String,String> map = Pattern.compile("\\s*&\\s*")
                .splitAsStream(requestUri.trim())
                .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length > 1 ? a[1]: ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Jersey library (`com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriComponent` or `org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriComponent` class):

```
String queryComponent = "name=raju&school=abcd&college=mnop&color=black&fruit=mango";
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = UriComponent.decodeQuery(queryComponent, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jackson json parser. Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now use ObjectMapper to create Map from json string:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map list = mapper.readValue(requestUri, Map.class);
```